# Asynchronous and synchronous methods

Tags: c#, async-await

I have an asynchronous method:

```
public async Task<Foo> GetFooAsync();
```

And I need its synchronous version. Something like this:

```
public Foo GetFoo();
```

I do not really want to totally rewrite code of `GetFooAsync` and I would like to do something such as

```
public Foo GetFoo() 
{
    return GetFooAsync().GetAwaiter().GetResult();
}
```

Is it good idea or this method has any unobvious problems? As I know if I use `GetFooAsync().Result` in synchronous context I may face with deadlock. But what about `GetFooAsync().GetAwaiter().GetResult()`?

Comment: ``return GetFooAsync().Result;`` ?

Comment: Don't use `.Result` use `.GetAwaiter().GetResult()` because the latter handles aggregate exceptions, the former does not.

Comment: If you want a synchronous version then add a shync overload separately

Comment: @Rahul apparently I don't understand. Could you to explain you idea with an example?

Comment: @EhsanSajjad as I know if I use `GetFooAsync().Result` in synchronous context I may face with deadlock. But what about `GetFooAsync().GetAwaiter().GetResult()`?

Comment: I would agree with Rahul here, don't wrap your async method with a sync call. Bite the bullet and rewrite it.

Comment: Have a look at Stephen C's AsyncEx Synchronous Task Extentions: https://github.com/StephenCleary/AsyncEx/blob/master/src/Nito.AsyncEx.Tasks/SynchronousTaskExtensions.cs

Comment: @DavidG why I shouldn't wrap async method?

Answer (score 4):

Mixing synchronous/async code may lead to deadlocks [as described in this article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/jj991977.aspx) (paragraph 'Async all the way').

Problem is where `Task` continuation runs and that depends on current [`SynchronizationContext`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.synchronizationcontext(v=vs.110).aspx). If the synchronization is meant to be scheduled on the same thread that's currently blocked by call to `Wait()`/`Result`/`GetResult()` you're running into trouble

Answer (score 3):

If you want a synchronous version then add a shynchronous overload of the method separately in order to have SOC (Separation Of Concern). I.c, add an overload like below as you have already done

```
public Foo GetFoo() 
{
  ///code body
}
```

Comment: In general should a synchronous version be written first, and then modified for async (maybe with flags), or can the synced version simply be wrapped in a worker thread to make in async?

Comment: @samusarin, No, as stated in answer it's always better to have two different version of the method and the same can be seen even in .NET BCL's

Answer (score 3):

You should *not* hide an asynchronous implementation behind a synchronously running method, e.g. by using

```
Task.Run(async () => await GetFooAsync());
```

Either implement the synchronous version separately or let the consumer explicitly synchronize the GetFooAsync.
The problem is, that running the task will consume worker threads and the pool of available workers is limited. You could run into blocking code. So the API consumer should be aware of that the synchronous implementation is asynchronously processed.

Comment: What if you changed name to `public Foo SynchronisedGetFooAsync() `? So that consumers know its just a wrapper for an async method.